# Multiple Tables Load from Snowflake to Snowflake using ADF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have source tables in Snowflake and Destination tables in Snowflake.

I need to load data from source to destination using ADF.

Requirement: I need to load data using single pipeline for all the tables.

Eg:  For suppose i have 40 tables in source and load the total 40 tables data to destination tables. I need to create a single pipeline to load all tables at a time.

[image: 1]

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad question. So take this all as general thoughts, more than specific advice.

Feel free to ask more specific questions, and I'll try to update/expand on this.

- ADF is useful as an orchestration/monitoring process, but can be tricky to manage the actual copying and maneuvering of data in Snowflake. My high level recommendation is to write your logic and loading code in snowflake stored procedures

  - then you can use ADF to orchestrate by simply calling those stored procedures. You get the benefits of using ADF for what it is good at, and allow Snowflake to do the heavy lifting, which is what it is good at.
  - hopefully you'd be able to parameterize procedures so that you can have one procedure (or a few) that takes a table name and dynamically figures out column names and the like to run your loading process.
- Assorted Notes on implementation.

  - ADF does have a native Snowflake connector. It is fairly new, so a lot of online posts will tell you how to set up a custom ODBC connector. You don't need to do this. Use the native connector and auto resolve integration and it should work for you.
  - You can write a query in an ADF lookup activity to output your list of tables, along with any needed parameters (like primary key, order by column, procedure name to call, etc.), then feed that list into an ADF foreach loop.
  - foreach loops are a little limited in that there are some things that you can't nest inside of a loop (like conditionals). If you need extra functionality, you can have the foreach loop call a child ADF pipeline (passing in those parameters) and have the child pipline manage your table processing logic.
  - Snowflake has pretty good options for querying metadata based on a tablename. See [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html). Between that and just a tiny bit of javascript logic, it's not too bad to generate dynamic queries (e.g. with column names specific to a provided tablename).
  - If you do want to use ADF's Copy Activities, I think You'll need to set up an intermediary Azure Storage Account connection. I believe this is because it uses COPY INTO under the hood which requires using external storage.
  - ADF doesn't have many good options for avoiding running one pipeline multiple times at once. Either be careful about making sure that your code can handle edge cases like this, or that your scheduling/timeouts won't allow for that scenario with a pipeline running too long.
- Extra note:

  - I don't know how tied you are to ADF, but without more context, I might suggest a quick look into DBT for this use case. It's a great tool for this specific scenario of Snowflake to Snowflake processing/transforming. My team's been much happier since moving some of our projects from ADF to DBT. (not sponsored :P )